# Python Quiz using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

For a project, I need to create an educational program and I have chosen a quiz. I am having trouble making the program recognise that flag has been incremented to 3. Is it an issue with how I am incrementing flag or something else?. I am not too familiar with python (or tkinter for that matter) so please don't be too harsh.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)

frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
frame3 = ttk.Frame(notebook)

notebook.add(frame1, text="Q1")
notebook.add(frame2, text="Q2")
notebook.add(frame3, text="Q3")

def displayscore(total):
    score = Tk()
    score.geometry("760x450")
    score.title("Score")
    score.configure(background="#000138")
    Label(score, text="Your score is:", fg="Black", font="Arial 36").pack()
    Label(score, textvariable=total, fg="Black", font="Arial 36").pack()


def flagset():
    flag.set(flag.get() + 1)
    if flag == 3:
        displayscore(total)

def totalset():
    total.set(total.get() + 1)

def main():

    #Question 1

    def correct1():
        clear1()
        totalset()
        flagset()

    def clear1():
        list = frame1.grid_slaves()
        for l in list:
            l.destroy()
        Label(frame1, text="Where is the '7' in 1704?").grid(row=0)
        flagset()

    Label(frame1, text="Where is the '7' in 1704?").grid(row=0)

    Button(frame1, text="In the Thousands", command=clear1, width=15).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    Button(frame1, text="In the Hundreds", command=correct1, width=15).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
    Button(frame1, text="In the Tens", command=clear1, width=15).grid(row=3, sticky=W)
    Button(frame1, text="In the Ones", command=clear1, width=15).grid(row=4, sticky=W)

    #Question2

    def correct2():
        clear2()
        totalset()
        flagset()

    def clear2():
        list = frame2.grid_slaves()
        for l in list:
            l.destroy()
        Label(frame2, text="What is 1704 in words?").grid(row=0)
        flagset()

    Label(frame2, text="What is 1704 in words?").grid(row=0)

    Button(frame2, text="One Million, Seven thousand and Four", command=clear2, width=35).grid(row=1, sticky=W)
    Button(frame2, text="One Hundred and Seventy Four", command=clear2, width=35).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
    Button(frame2, text="One Thousand and Seventy Four", command=clear2, width=35).grid(row=3, sticky=W)
    Button(frame2, text="One Thousand, Seven Hundred and Four", command=correct2, width=35).grid(row=4, sticky=W)

    #Question 3

    def correct3():
        clear3()
        totalset()
        flagset()

    def clear3():
        list = frame3.grid_slaves()
        for l in list:
            l.destroy()
        Label(frame3, text="Find ?: 3 x ? = 18").grid(row=0, column=2)
        flagset()

    Label(frame3, text="Find ?: 3 x ? = 18").grid(row=0, column=2)

    Button(frame3, text="6", command=correct3, width=15).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
    Button(frame3, text="7", command=clear3, width=15).grid(row=2, sticky=W)
    Button(frame3, text="8", command=clear3, width=15).grid(row=3, sticky=W)
    Button(frame3, text="9", command=clear3, width=15).grid(row=4, sticky=W)

flag = IntVar()
total = IntVar()

main()

notebook.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **minimal** [mcve]. What this means is isolate your problem to the few lines (still runnable in isolation) which exhibit the problem you are facing.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flag` is a tkinter `IntVar`, so `flag == 3` will never be true.
Instead, use `flag.get() == 3`.

Also, when a correct answer is given, you increment `flag` twice, once in the `clear` function and once in the `correct` function.

Also also, you run `flagset` (from `clear`) before you run `totalset`, so with the last answer `total` will not be updated before you show the score.

Comment: Now that I've fixed 'flag', there seems to be an issue with displaying what score is. It just prints: "Your total is:" " ". Any help?

Comment: Ah yes I missed that. The problem is that you make two instances of `Tk()`. Instead, for extra windows you should use `Toplevel()`. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045508/3714930) for more information on why you shouldn't have two instances of `Tk()`.